# How to get synonyms of a word from Thesaurus using Google Sheets importxml function

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

I'm trying to make personal dictionary by Google Sheet.
I got a free template on website. But now the synonym column doesn't work.
I try to change XPath query by myself, XPath helper on google extension. But it's still doesn't work.
Could you help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Uqq.png)

I expect someone can help me in XPath query

Comment: Hi BaRon! Welcome to StackOverflow. I similarly have issues getting it working. Your best bet might be to use IMPORTJSON and use a thesaurus API

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one **alternative** if you wish to try out:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,let(Λ,trim(index(importxml("https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/"&Σ,"//div[1]/div[1]/span[2]"),1,2)),
          substitute(index(split(substitute(Λ," ","|",20),"|"),1,1),char(10),)))))
```

- *restricted the word count to `20` within formula; change it to your choice...*

[image]